# EMR: How to download Hive logs without using SSH?

Tags: logging, ssh, hive, amazon-emr

I'm using Hive on AWS EMR and I'm trying to access the Hive logs. All blogs I've seen recommend using SSH to access these logs, but SSH access to the cluster has been blocked for security reasons.

**Is there an alternative way to download these logs?**

Comment: Depends on the remaining services. If even `SSH` is blocked, what isn't blocked (HTTP, TFTP, Telnet) ?

Comment: Sure, enable logging to s3 then Grant s3 access to users who should see the logs